# visual WADL editor

Tags: wadl

WADL seams to be the better (light-weight) way to annotate REST Services.

My question:
Do you know a visual Tool (Online, Eclipse Plugin or other) to create and manage the WADL Specification?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For online I have used this to validate WADLs with good results.
http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/

You can obtain the XSD for the WADL from W3C site here:
http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/wadl.xsd

The online tool is very straight forward to use. Your WADL goes in the left-hand pane and the XSD in the other one. It takes a while to validate so you might have to coax your browser a bit ...

I have also used oXygen against the same XSD and would recommend it over the online tool. It checks as you type so if you're authoring a lot of WADLs then it's really worth it the license.
http://www.oxygenxml.com/

The other visual tool is XML Spy from Altova. I haven't used this for a while but they have a good range of products and worth considering if you can use other tools from their package, e.g. diffdog is supposed to be very good.
http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html

Finally the Netbeans IDE has support, but it seems a bit overkill to run an IDE in order to author a WADL. This is not lightweight :-)

Answer (score 2):

I find [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/getting-started.html) excellent for editing WADL definitions and creating API contracts (and can do the same for WSDL).

While it is not visual in the same way xmlspy is; its structured approach is much better for establish a WebService 'contract'.  It can then optionally be used to create Test Cases and Service Mocks.

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised the answer above was accepted, they are only links for tools validating the WADL, not creating it. Altova's XMLSpy indeed has nice visual **WSDL** editor but there is no option for **WADL**. You can only edit it there as normal XML but then you only get normal XML editor.

The closest thing to visual WADL editor I found is this plugin to Eclipse:

http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-10.html

You can see on the pictures below you have a visual editor for defining the service and it then generates Jersey REST service ... from where you can get WADL.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this WADL generator which can also load existing wadl file and create PHP, Ruby, PYTHON, Java or C# classes:

http://tomayac.de/rest-describe/latest/RestDescribe.html

You can also download the source code from here:

http://blog.tomayac.com/index.php?date=2007-05-28&time=19:34:40&perma=Generate+Python+from+your+WADL+REST+API+Descriptions+with+REST+Describe+%26+Compile.html